# Altering references within a reference parameter

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass an array to a method. The array contains objects which need to be nulled. The method would simply null each object in a loop. I need this to reflect back in the caller.

Sample code (code goodness & minor syntactical issues can be ignored):

```
public class ABC
{
  ...
}

private void SomeMethod()
{
  var toBeNulledObj1 = new ABC();
  var toBeNulledObj2 = new ABC();
  var arrayOfNullableObjects = new ABC[]{toBeNulledObj1 ,toBeNulledObj2};
  NullingFunction(arrayOfNullableObjects);
}

private void NullingFunction(ABC[] arrayOfNullableObjects)
{
   for(int i = 0; i< arrayOfNullableObjects.Length ; i++)
     {
        arrayOfNullableObjects[i] = null;
     }
}
```

Clearly upon returning, `toBeNulledObj1` & `toBeNulledObj2` are not null but retain their older values though `arrayOfNullableObjects` now has two `null` objects. I realise that ref & out only apply to the collection parameter (here, `arrayOfNullableObjects` which doesn't even need a ref). I tried passing them in as `params` instead of a collection but that doesn't help, either (ref & params cannot be combined).

Question: How can I alter each/any object in a collection of objects within a method such that the change is visible to the caller? I am not altering the collection itself. Please note, I am not changing the contents/members of `toBeNulledObj1` but the reference itself (to either null or a new object).

Comment: Not possible. They will still hold the references. What exactly are you wanting to do.

Comment: You should see: [Parameter passing in C# by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: @Habib I did read through it & [Albahari's](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) too. Very useful but not to solve my problem.

Comment: You can't do that in C#. However, what is the problem you are actually trying to solve? There is probably another way to do it.

Comment: @cheedep I want to alter object reference based on a rule. Often the rules is simply to null them out. Rather than do them in place in SomeMethod() & (kinda) repeat that snippet in other classes too, I thought I could have a processor built which takes a collection of objects & the rules to apply on them to alter them. Another place where I would need that would be in the Dispose() of IDisposable classes. You pretty much doing the same thing to all of those objects.

Soner Gönül Thanks a tonne for the edits. :-)

Comment: You can use the "using" statement

Comment: @Cheedep: Tell us how? :)

Comment: @A_K: Is unsafe code allowed?

Comment: @MartinMulder I was only saying about the IDisposables

Comment: @MartinMulder I would like to see your suggestion. I am willing to try anything! :-)

Comment: You are trying to set the obj `toBeNulledObj1` to null,it's impossible,but I notice you said '(to either null or a new object)'.And to change the obj `toBeNulledObj1` is possible,so I suggest that you tell us what the exactly you want to do.

Comment: @jarvanJiang can you help me understand how you differentiate between assigning null to an object and assigning some other reference? What I want to do is has been stated in the question as well as my comment to cheedep. Please tell me what exactly you don't get & I shall clarify.

Comment: I had checked what you reply to cheedep.But that is just what you are trying to do but what you want to do by this or why are you trying to do this.If your `toBeNulledObj` will used by judging it is null,why don't you using a property to mark it is already 'set to null'.What I am saying,is it's very hard to do this way,maybe change another direction.

Comment: @cheedep: Using `using` and `IDisposable` does not set the references to `null`.

Comment: @A_K: If you want to set these variables with not only nulls, but also other values, why do those variables have to be values inside a method. Why not put those values into a class (as properties), so you can set them in multiple ways.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution #1: Unsafe code

One solution is using a unsafe code. You have to think twice before using it, and I do not know if you will be happy with my answer, but here it is.

```
static private void SomeMethod()
{
    ABC toBeNulledObj1 = new ABC();
    ABC toBeNulledObj2 = new ABC();

    IntPtr[] arrayOfNullableObjects = new IntPtr[] { MakeReference(ref toBeNulledObj1), MakeReference(ref toBeNulledObj2) };
    NullingFunction(arrayOfNullableObjects);
}

static private void NullingFunction(IntPtr[] arrayOfNullableObjects)
{
    foreach (IntPtr reference in arrayOfNullableObjects)
        ClearReference(reference);
}

/// <summary>
/// Makes the reference to the reference value of a reference type.
/// </summary>
static unsafe private IntPtr MakeReference<T>(ref T value)
    where T: class
{
    TypedReference reference = __makeref(value);
    return *(IntPtr*)&reference;
}

/// <summary>
/// Clears the reference to a reference type, using a reference to that reference value.
/// </summary>
static unsafe private void ClearReference(IntPtr reference)
{
    if (sizeof(IntPtr) == 4)
        *((int*)reference) = 0;
    else
        *((long*)reference) = 0;
}
```

## Solution #2: Anonymous class

The second solution could be done by using an anonymous class which holds your data. The fields inside this anonymous class are cleared. A disadvantage is that you have a second class and the reference to this class also should to be cleared. (This can be done by adding `ref` to `o` and in the `NullingFunction` set `o` to `null`.)  Of course you can also use a predefined class, but his solution is the closest to your code in your OP.

```
public static void SomeMethod()
{
    var container = new
    {
        toBeNulledObj1 = new ABC(),
        toBeNulledObj2 = new ABC(),
    };

    NullingFunction(container);
}

private static void NullingFunction<T>(T container)
    where T : class
{
    if (container == null)
        return;
    foreach(FieldInfo f in container.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
        if (f.FieldType.IsClass)
            f.SetValue(container, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempts, Martin. The 2nd solution would still not work. Your nulling out `o` would deny me the opportunity to check if the contained objects are also nulled out in the caller. Edited your code to show that they will not be nulled. Trying out 1...

Comment: @A_K: Done. I removed the last line and the `ref` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want to set them to null, do you mean that you want to destroy the object?

C# has automatic garbage collection, so as soon as an object goes out of scope (that is, when no other objects make reference to it), the garbage collector will destroy it.

In the code above, the label "tobeNulledObj1" still refers to an object, and your array also points to it before you call the NullingFunction.

After you call the NullingFunction, you still have one reference pointing to the object (that is, tobeNulledObj1). If you set tobeNulledObj1 to null, then the Garbage Collector will collect it.

EDIT: I second cheedep's question - what is it exactly that you are trying to do? What do you want your variables to hold at the end?

Comment: Nulling them is an example. Please see my comments to cheedep along with the question. I might want them to point to some other object.

Comment: I think I understand what you want now. You're saying that if you set array[0] to null, you want tobeNulledObj1 to be null when you return. BASarat is correct: "Then there is nothing that function B can do to change the reference that toBeNulledObj1 / 2 points to."

Answer (score 0):

If function A holds a reference to a variable i.e:

```
  var toBeNulledObj1 = new ABC();
  var toBeNulledObj2 = new ABC();
```

And does not pass this into function B:

```
private NullingFunction(ABC[] arrayOfNullableObjects)
```

Then there is ***nothing*** that function B can do to change the reference that toBeNulledObj1 / 2 points to.

Since ref is not allowed along with params (as you mentioned):

```
 private void NullingFunction(ref params ABC[] arrayOfNullableObjects)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNullableObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            arrayOfNullableObjects[i] = null;
        }
    }
```

The available alternative is to create overloads e.g.:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    var toBeNulledObj1 = new ABC();
    var toBeNulledObj2 = new ABC();
    NullingFunction(ref toBeNulledObj1, ref toBeNulledObj2);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private void NullingFunction(ref ABC one)
{
    one = null;
}

private void NullingFunction(ref ABC one, ref ABC two)
{
    one = null;
    two = null;
}
```

Comment: I suspected that. Was hoping there was some hack to achieve that.

Comment: The parameter list would just be `(ref ABC one)` or `(ref ABC one, ref ABC two)` in your alternative. No arrays required. This would only help if the number of objects that I might have to pass is known. Right now that is not the case & the number might vary.

Answer (score 0):

Is wrapping acceptable?

```
class Wrapped<T> where T : new() {
   private T val = new T();
   ...
   public void Nullify() { val = null; }
}

private void SomeMethod()
{
  var toBeNulledObj1 = new Wrapped<ABC>();
  var toBeNulledObj2 = new Wrapped<ABC>();
  var arrayOfNullableObjects = new Wrapped<ABC>[]{toBeNulledObj1 ,toBeNulledObj2};
  NullingFunction(arrayOfNullableObjects);

  Debug.Assert(toBeNulledObj1.Get() == null);
  // Or...
  Debug.Assert(toBeNulledObj1.IsDefined == false);
  // Or...
  Debug.Assert(toBeNulledObj1.IsNull == true);
}

private void NullingFunction(Wrapped<ABC>[] arrayOfNullableObjects)
{
   for(int i = 0; i< arrayOfNullableObjects.Length ; i++)
     {
        arrayOfNullableObjects[i].Nullify();
     }
}
```

(Disclaimer: hand-compiled code :) may contain errors)

If you need it as a general pattern, you can make NullingFunction parametric (T, U), with a constaint `where U: Wrapped<T>`

The idea is to make something similar to `Nullable` for ref types, or something that looks like a smart pointer, if you are familiar with C++.

Thus, wrapper could have `T Get()` (or an implicit conversion to T) to get out the value, an `IsDefined` property, and so on.